# Ember Data findQuery is not updating relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm updating to latest ED and have been successful in most migrations but a part of my app has broken where it worked on 0.14. The following is an example of my scenario:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  times: DS.hasMany('time')
});

App.Time = DS.Model.extend({
  start: DS.attr(),
  end: DS.attr(),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});
```

I pass an array of times along with the user when they are first fetched (lets say `user.get('times.length'); // 20` upon initial load and sideload), then as I scroll through a calendar, I execute a findQuery for more times:

```
this.store.find('time', {
  start: '...',
  end: '...',
  user_id: 'x'
});
```

I now have the freshly loaded `time` records in the store as expected, with valid starts and ends and with a correct `user` belongsTo relation.

```
this.store.all('time').filterBy('user', user).get('length'); // 40
```

What one would expect (and what occurred in 0.14) would be to find the freshly loaded times in the list of associated times on that user, but what I get is:

```
user.get('times.length'); // 20 (still)
```

I'm using an ActiveModelAdapter. Am I doing something wrong? Perhaps this is expected and I missed a memo? I will draft a jsbin in the coming days unless someone has a simple answer in the meantime.

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8+canary.db4febb4
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on the `user.times` relationship to update, I discovered the `filter` method on the store.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

In the controller where I needed the times, I initialized the controller with the following:

```
init: function() {
  var _this = this;
  this._super();
  this.store.filter(App.Time, function(time) {
    user.get('user.id') === _this.get('user.id');
  }).then(function(records) {
    // A bound RecordArray is returned, which we can set to a property of this
    // controller and we can trust that it will be updated when the result of the
    // filter changes
    _this.set('times', records);
  });
}
```

And voila, we can build computed properties upon the `times` property on our controller and expect them to update when a new time is loaded into the store.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `findQuery` and set up the query manually with ajax, then passed the results to `pushPayload`, which sideloaded the relationships.

This is in my route file:

```
model: function(params) {
    const name = params.name;

    return ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/students',
      data: {'name': name},
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).then(res => {
      this.store.pushPayload('student', res);
      return this.store.findAll('student', {'name': name});
    }).then(students => {
      return students.filterBy('name', name)[0];
    });
  },
```